# Postgres index together or hash field with index it?

Tags: django, postgresql, hash

I have a Django model with 10 fields, which describe a change of other objects.

While I'm creating new change, I must find if change already exists. This is because changes are generating in parallel.

When I checking it, I use filter on 8 fields (some ints, some strings). And now I have index_together on it, but I think what if I will generate hash from this 8 fields and insert as 11 field in model, then just filter using this field?

Of course, on hash field will be an index.

Comment: yes, this is a generally accepted approach when large data sets need to be compared

Comment: if you want a specific answer post your model along with an indication of how many rows you have etc etc